# Jenkins Pipeline sh: command not found - are certain commands not available now?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following stage in my Jenkins pipeline:

```
stage('Update Android SDK') {
    withEnv(['ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Shared/android-sdk-macosx',
             'PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH'
    ]) {
        sh 'echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform,tool,platform-tool,extra-android-m2repository'
}
```

This used to work perfectly. However, I just updated to Jenkins 2.44 and the latest Pipeline plugins and since then, the `android` command doesn't run anymore. Here's the error message from the jenkins log:

```
+ android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform,tool,platform-tool,extra-android-m2repository
/Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/d_release-3-0-3dummy.1gpbab-FJUYVCADYU5YVX7LNYATQTVORNDAKFSYICGSZRW4QXTUW5E2OMEQ@tmp/durable-f249f287/script.sh: line 2: android: command not found
```

**And it isn't just `android`**. It looks to me like some security setting has changed or something, and certain commands can't run via the `sh` pipeline command anymore. For example, `echo` and `pwd` still work, but `which` or `ls` don't:

```
+ echo /Users/Shared/android-sdk-macosx
/Users/Shared/android-sdk-macosx

++ which android
/Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/d_rel/script.sh: line 2: which: command not found
+ echo
[Pipeline] sh
[d_rel] Running shell script
+ pwd
/Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/d_rel
[Pipeline] sh
[d_rel] Running shell script
+ ls -la /Users/Shared/
/Users/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/d_rel/script.sh: line 2: ls: command not found
```

(I've replaced the string `d_release-3-0-3dummy.1gpbab-FJUYVCADYU5YVX7LNYATQTVORNDAKFSYICGSZRW4QXTUW5E2OMEQ@tmp/durable-f249f287` with `d_rel` in the snippet above to improve readability.)

### What changed? If certain commands are restricted now, what can I do to enable all commands to run?

Comment: What if your script is just `env`? That should help debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something structured like:

```
withEnv(['ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Shared/android-sdk-macosx',]) {
    withEnv(["PATH+ADK=${env.ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${env.ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools"]) {
        sh 'echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform,tool,platform-tool,extra-android-m2repository'
    }
}
```

I don't think `$ANDROID_HOME` will get expanded correctly otherwise.  An [example](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#maven-and-jdk-specific-version) of using a variable that was just defined is in the official Pipeline Examples doc.

The `PATH+XYZ` thing seems to be the [suggested](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/EnvVars.html) way to append to `$PATH`.

Comment: That did it! It was a PATH issue. The PATH was getting mangled which resulted in `android` (and every other command) not being found. Note: In order to use the previously defined `$ANDROID_HOME` env var, I had to introduce a nested `withEnv`. Updated your solution with that tweak.